# How can i populate form from selected Kendo Grid row

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following code to populate form from selected Kendo Grid, the grid is selectable, how can i fix to make it work?

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var grid = $("#AddressGrid").data("kendoGrid");
          fillForm(grid.dataItem);

      var fillForm = function(dataItem) {
        var columns = $("#AddressGrid").data("kendoGrid").options.columns;
        var form = $("form");

        for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
          var field = columns[i].field;
          form.find("#" + field).val(dataItem[field]);
        }
      }
    });
</script>
```

Here is my form looks like

```
<form>

    <label>ID:</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="AddressLine2" /><br />
    <label>Name:</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="City" /><br />
    <label>Last Name:</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="AddressID" />
</form>
```

Comment: If it is just a small number of fields, try `$("#AddressLine2").val(dataItem.AddressLine2)` etc.

Comment: @SteveGreene yes very few number of fields,  I have a hard time modifying the js can you show me more on how to modify for loop in my js in the answer section? thats what i am looking

Comment: @SteveGreene yes very few number of fields,  I have a hard time modifying the js can you show me more on how to modify for loop in my js, will be great if you show me in the answer section. that's what i was looking

Answer (score 1):

The big problem I see with your code is you have not named the select event and referenced it in your grid. If you want to do it the reflection style way:

```
...
.Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
.Events(events => events.Change("onSelect"))
...
```

You would define the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function fillForm(dataItem) {
        var columns = $("#AddressGrid").data("kendoGrid").options.columns;
        var form = $("form");

        for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
          var field = columns[i].field;
          form.find("#" + field).val(dataItem[field]);
        }
    }

    function onSelect() {
        var grid = $("#AddressGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        fillForm(grid.dataItem);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, where can i put this `Events(events => events.Change("onSelect"))`, My grid configuration is a bit different

Comment: I tried it as `  $("#AddressGrid").on("change", onSelect);`

Comment: Are you using an MVC grid (wrappers) or javascript? Both allow you to setup events that are listened for, so no need to do a separate `on(xxxx,fn)`. See [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/change) and [here](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/events).

Comment: hi steve i am using mvc grid

Comment: Then you should use the `.Events...` syntax to subscribe to the change event and call the onSelect method that will populate the form. Example of change event and selection is here: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/events